# how to read tab separated line into variables

Tags: zsh

I wrote this function in zsh

```
function test() {
  test="a\tb\tc"

  while IFS=$'\t' read -r user host key; do
    echo "user: $user"
    echo "host: $host"
    echo "key: $key"
  done <<< "$test"
}
```

The output was:

```
user: a b   c
host:
key:
```

if instead of

```
... IFS=$'\t' read -r ...
```

I change it to

```
... IFS='\t' read -r ...
```

the output is

```
user: a
host:
key: b  c
```

Just what is going on?

I would like to read the tab separated line and set my variables accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the double-quotes to `$'...'` (single quotes preceded by a `$`) could rescue for the variable `$test`:

```
test=$'a\tb\tc'
```

Here is the zsh manual for QUOTING (double-quoting and `$'...'`):

> QUOTING
> ...
> A string enclosed between `$'` and `'` is processed the same way as the string arguments of the [`print`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print) builtin
> ...
> Inside  double  quotes  (`""`), parameter and command substitution occur, and `\` quotes the characters `\`, `` ` ``, `"`, `$`, and the first character of `$histchars` (default `!`).
>
> --- [zshmisc(1), QUOTING](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-quoting)

For example:

- `"\$"` -> `$`, `"\!"` -> `!` etc.
- `"\t"` -> `\t` (zsh does not recognize as <kbd>tab</kbd> this case), `"\a"` ->  `\a` etc.

It does not treat the escape sequence `\t` as <kbd>tab</kbd> when it is used inside double quotes, so `"a\tb\tc"` does not mean "a<kbd>tab</kbd>b<kbd>tab</kbd>c". (But things are a little more complicated: builtin [`echo`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-echo) recognizes the escape sequence `\t`.)

### (1)  `... IFS=$'\t' read -r ...` (the original form)

Because expanding `"$test"` dose not have any <kbd>tab</kbd> characters, so [`read`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read) assigns the whole line to `$user`:

```
user: a b   c
host:
key:
```

(But [`echo`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-echo) recognizes the escape sequence `\t` as the <kbd>tab</kbd>.)

### (2)  `... IFS='\t' read -r ...`

Again, expanding `"$test"` does not have any <kbd>tab</kbd> characters, so [`read`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-read) separate the field by `\` and `t` according [`$IFS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-IFS).
`a\t\b\tc` splits into `a` (to `$user`), `\`(separator), `` (empty to `$host`), `t`(separator), and the rest of the line (`b\tc` to `$key`):

```
user: a
host:
key: b  c
```

(But again, [`echo`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-echo) recognizes the escape sequence `\t` as the <kbd>tab</kbd>.)

---

Here is the code changed from `test="..."` to `test=$'...'`:

```
function test() {
  test=$'a\tb\tc'

  while IFS=$'\t' read -r user host key; do
    echo "user: $user"
    echo "host: $host"
    echo "key: $key"
  done <<< "$test"
}
test
```

The output is:

```
user: a
host: b
key: c
```

PS: it is worth reading POSIX's Quoting specification, which is simpler than zsh's (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02)